# Password field of login screen is disabled

Tags: unity, keyboard, login, password

I'm using ubuntu 14.04, here in the 'login screen' the password field is disabled, this issue also occurs sometimes during 'lock screen'. I don't want to remove password from my account nor do i want auto login. My account is with administrator privileges.

Going to terminal using <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>, then back to GUI with <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd>, doesn't enables the password field.

Comment: may be resetting/reinstalling `unity` will help?

Answer (score 2):

I'm having the exact same issue.
Edit: Looks like this is a confirmed bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1311316

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue and went to the terminal via <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>, logged in through terminal, then executed the `unity` command, then went back to the GUI with <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd> and my system resumed to where I had left it.  No restart required.

Comment: This worked for me, although I executed `unity --replace` instead of just `unity`. However, the cause of this is frustrating.

Comment: I've tried `unity`, `unity --replace`, and `compiz --replace` and what I got was a single window maximized across both monitors. There was no menu bar and no way to access the desktop.

Comment: Note that this solution only partially works for me when I have multiple users logged in. When unity comes back up, it logs me in as one of them, and the other one's state (windows, applications) is lost, and there's no way to switch users.

Answer (score 2):

I found a very nice work-around in comment 166 of the bug report (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1311316):

- Switch to a tty (e.g. Ctrl+Alt+F1)
- Log in
- Run: sudo loginctl unlock-sessions
- Switch back to the Desktop: Ctrl+Alt+F7 (or F8).