# No password input field on lock screen

Tags: unity, 14.04, ati

Occasionally my lock screen does this:

[image: No password input]

That makes logging in difficult. [Restarting Unity](https://askubuntu.com/a/38597/59841) kind of works, sometimes only a reboot will fix it. My video card is a Sapphire Radeon HD 6870 with dual displays using the open drivers.

Comment: This might be a bug.  Take a look at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1311316

Comment: Had the same problem, mostly occuring when training neural networks using `Caffe`.  `unity --replace` makes the login screen go away, but everything else seems corrupted. So I still had to reboot :(

Answer (score 4):

Reloading unity restores the password input on the login screen for me (Ubuntu 14.04 with a Nvidia GPU).

1. Switch to an alternate terminal using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.
2. Reload unity with:

   ```bash
   nohup unity --replace &
   ```
3. Switch back to your graphical terminal using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>. You may have to wait several seconds if you see a black screen.

Unity sort of works after this but you can at least save your work in progress:

- The compiz grid plugin seems to think multiple monitors are now a single monitor.
- The global menu bar no longer works.
- Menus in window title bars no longer work (if enabled).
- Custom global keyboard shortcuts don't work.

Comment: Note: In more recent versions, the --replace option is deprecated. :(

Comment: This worked to recover my desktop but killed all my running task!  I think I may have to part with Unity as it is not reliable.

Comment: This has the strange side-effect of making me enter my password twice to log in. (14.04)

Comment: If nothing else works, try entering your username login in ALL LOWERCASE. I pulled my hair out before finally coming to this solution!

Comment: This works, albeit with the really hilarious side-effect of requiring me to enter my password twice whenever I unlock. As you said, sort of works, and rebooting is probably the best way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on an HP with Radeon 6370 graphics.  I'm still using open source graphics, but I'm using the versions that came from the [oibaf repository](https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/graphics-drivers/) - they are a little 'edgier' than the stock open source, but not as edgy as xorg-edgers.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

installs the drivers

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers
```

removes the drivers.

Comment: Tried this one, and it didn't seem to work. Did I have to reboot after installing the new drivers?

Comment: Yes you would need to reboot.

Answer (score 0):

open terminal
CTRL+ALT+F3

reset the unity

```
$ unity-reset
$ setsid unity
```

if that didnt workout try to re-install the unity & the desktop

```
$ sudo apt-get autoremove ubuntu-desktop 
$ sudo apt-get autoremove unity 
$ sudo apt-get update 
$ sudo apt-get install unity
$ sudo apt-get install unity-2d 
$ sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop 
$ sudo shutdown -r
```

now install the ati driver

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install fglrx gksu
$ sudo amdconfig --initial && sudo shutdown -r
```

after the reboot 
 u can run the driver buy ALT + F2
copy & past this

```
gksu amdcccle
```

Comment: How would reinstalling Unity fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This can be worked around without losing your session by:

1. Switch to a tty (e.g. `Ctrl+Alt+F1`)
2. Log in
3. Run: `sudo loginctl unlock-sessions`
4. Switch back to the Desktop: `Ctrl+Alt+F7` (or F8).

From [the bug report fori this issue](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1311316) and [this answer to a similar question](https://askubuntu.com/a/920387/344674)