# Wake from suspend, password field missing?

Tags: login, suspend, lightdm

Ubuntu 14.04. Brightness & Lock settings are to turn off screen after 10 minutes and lock screen after 30 minutes. 50% of the time, when I wake my computer from suspend, the login field to enter my password is missing. Quite annoying. I have to CTRL + ALT + 3 to get to another.... shell? (still new-ish to Linux), log in and run:

**sudo service lightdm restart**

Where can I look to see what is going wrong. Is there a lightdm log of some kind?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The lightdm log can be viewed by running `sudo less /var/log/lightdm/lightdm.log`

The issue you're describing is a [known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1311316).  A few potential workarounds are shown in the comments on that ticket.  One workaround is to drop into a terminal by pressing `ctrl+alt+F1`, logging in, and then running `unity --replace`.  Other variations are shown in the bug comments.

Comment: Erm, your answer *is* correct, but `sudo less /var/log/lightdm/lightdm.log`  would have been more informative to a user that is asking where the lightdm log is...  ;-)  (please [edit] and change and flesh it out a bit.

Answer (score 0):

This can be worked around without losing your session by:

1. Switch to a tty (e.g. `Ctrl+Alt+F1`)
2. Log in
3. Run: `sudo loginctl unlock-sessions`
4. Switch back to the Desktop: `Ctrl+Alt+F7` (or F8).

From [the bug report fori this issue](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1311316) and [this answer to a similar question](https://askubuntu.com/a/920387/344674)

Answer (score 0):

I see in some cases it could be linked to the use of Nvidia drivers.  See potential solution at https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2395562&highlight=suspend+resume+problems