# Ubuntu 16.04 does not offer password prompt after entering username

Tags: password

At login I get the prompt for username 
After entering my username and pressing enter I get the screen below
https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBsl4.jpg
Login with no prompt 
The mouse moves but that’s all
I’m able to login with tty 
Launching startx from tty gives me a desktop with only one folder and no icons for system preferences etc. 
Can you please help?
I have searched for a whole day and found nothing 
Thanks

Comment: Couldn’t post image as I’m a newbie. What I see is The word login and no option to enter password

Comment: Maybe this post helps https://askubuntu.com/questions/460378/password-field-of-login-screen-is-disabled

Comment: @IsekhuaEvborokhai just edit your post and add an imgur link that will be allowed